# Move element on each scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to move the "main" tagname by 100 viewport height upwards or downwards according to the wheel delta value to make the section inside the window change. And also a way to stop or start executing a code when specified, but I'm unable to figure out what the function should be to execute it properly.

```js
window.addEventListener("wheel", event => {

  const delta = Math.sign(event.deltaY);
  //console.info(delta);

  if (delta > 0) {
    nextSection();
  } else if (delta < 0) {
    previousSection();
  }

  let main = document.querySelector("main");
  var mainTop = main.style.top

  function nextSection() {
    console.log("next-section");


    let sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");

    let mainTop = "0";

    function countP() {
      mainTop += 100;
      main.style.top = mainTop;
    }

  }

  function previousSection() {
    console.log("previous-section");
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

main>section {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#first-section {
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#services {
  top: 100vh;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#about-us {
  top: 200vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#ecommerce {
  top: 300vh;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

#testimonials {
  top: 400vh;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33vh;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 67vh;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="english">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section id="first-section"></section>
    <section id="services"></section>
    <section id="about-us"></section>
    <section id="ecommerce"></section>
    <section id="testimonials"></section>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try putting your code into a snippet (There's an icon in the editor which looks like a document with `<>` inside it) Putting the code in there and trying to run it should highlight a few syntax errors which are the best place to start.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what your expected outcome is, but this seems like the perfect application for an Intersection Observer over those elements. Is the animation tied to the scroll velocity or the position in the window?